# jQuery get index of element but just inside its class

Tags: jquery

I have different HTML-Elements inside a div element:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="horse"></div>
    <div class="horse"></div>
    <div class="lion"></div>
    <div class="horse"></div>
    <div class="horse active"></div>
    <div class="elephant"></div>
    <div class="horse"></div>
    <div class="horse"></div>
</div>
```

From this list i need the index of the element with the class active. But i dont need the full index but just the index inside its class. When i use the jQuery index function:

```
 var activeElementInsideType = tabIndex;
```

I get the output of 4 but i need just the index inside the horse elments. The lion should not be counted and i should get the index of 3.

Comment: I have considered multiple active classes in my answer

Answer (score 3):

You can find relative index by doing

```
$('.wrapper').find(<CLASS_OF_ACTIVE>).index(<ACTIVE_ELEMENT>)
```

In order to do this, first you need to get the other class of element which has `.active` class. And then use `index()` method with the element as following

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
  $active = $('.wrapper').eq(0).find('.active').eq(0);
  // find() returns multiple elements. So in order to get a single element,
  // use eq(0) to get the first one.
  
  var classList = $active.attr('class').split(' ');
  
  // You can change the way of getting the 'horse' class
  var classOfActive = classList[0];
  
  var indexOfActive = $('.wrapper').find('.' + classOfActive).index($active)
  
  console.log(indexOfActive);
  
  
})
```

```html
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.4.1.min.js"
  integrity="sha256-CSXorXvZcTkaix6Yvo6HppcZGetbYMGWSFlBw8HfCJo="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="horse"></div>
    <div class="horse"></div>
    <div class="lion"></div>
    <div class="horse"></div>
    <div class="horse active"></div>
    <div class="elephant"></div>
    <div class="horse"></div>
   <div class="horse"></div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Can you check the below code

```
var index = 0;
var indexArr =[];
$('.wrapper').find('div').each(function(){

    if(   $( this ).hasClass( "horse" )  ) {         
         if( $( this ).hasClass( "active" ) ){
            indexArr.push(index)
         }
        index++;
    }   

});
console.log(indexArr);
```

Comment: I have considered multiple active classes in my answer

Answer (score 0):

You can clone the element and then remove the elements with class `lion` and find the index of active class:

```js
var elem = $('.wrapper').clone();
$(elem).find('.lion').remove();
var activeElem = $(elem).find('.active');
var index = $(elem).find('div').index(activeElem);
console.log(index);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="horse"></div>
    <div class="horse"></div>
    <div class="lion"></div>
    <div class="horse"></div>
    <div class="horse active"></div>
    <div class="elephant"></div>
    <div class="horse"></div>
    <div class="horse"></div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the following would do that:

```
$(".horse").index($(".active"));
```

Use the .horse class to create an array and then add the .active parameter to the .index() function to give you the index of .active only within .horse elements.

So this html:

```
<div class="wrapper">
    <div class="horse"></div>
    <div class="horse"></div>
    <div class="lion"></div>
    <div class="horse"></div>
    <div class="horse active"></div>
    <div class="elephant"></div>
    <div class="horse"></div>
    <div class="horse"></div>
</div>
```

Would return a value of 3.